# How to build directive name dynamically and bind this directive to element?

Tags: angular

How I can build a directive name and then bind this directive name to one of elements inside the component's template?

For example, I have a component that receives `alignment` as input. Based on this `alignment` value I want to build a directive name (if it was just a string it would be just `app-text-${alignment}`)

or something like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: `
        <div class="blahblahblah">
          <div [attr.app-text-{{ align }}]>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
          </div>
        </div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() align: 'left' | 'right' | 'center' = 'center';
}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: You could write a directive that sets certain attributes based on some `@Input()`. Personally not a fan, but that should work